# Firebase and Google Tag Manager : <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I integrated Firebase and GTM over cocoapods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'GoogleTagManager', '~> 5.0'
```

Podfile.lock for the versions used :

> - Firebase/Core (3.12.0):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.6.0)
>   - FirebaseCore (= 3.4.7)
> - FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0):
>
>   - FirebaseCore (~> 3.4)
>   - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
>   - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseCore (3.4.7):
>
>   - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
> - GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
> - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
>
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
> - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
> - GoogleTagManager (5.0.8):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3.0)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.1)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.1):
>
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
> - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
>
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)

and followed the steps in documentation for the integration but i am having non-stop warning of :

```
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: (null) with parameters: (null)
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event
```

Full Log from app start:

```
 Firebase automatic screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be automatically logged. To report screen transitions manually, call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:
 setupFirebase (670139-com.apple.main-thread)
 <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
 <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
 <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)
 <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
 <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
 GoogleTagManager info: Loading container: GTM-XXXXXXX
 GoogleTagManager info: Attempting to load saved version of container GTM-XXXXXXX
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: gtm.load with parameters: (null)
 GoogleTagManager warning: Invalid Event name: gtm.load (Must not start with an underscore and must consist of letters, digits and/or underscores)
 Should commit UiContext but SignalR is disconnected: nil (670139-com.apple.main-thread)
: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x125947998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x125769880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> setScreenName:screenClass: must be called after a view controller has appeared
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: openScreen with parameters: {
 System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/5F44EFE3-0BDF-402A-A01B-8F6EABB31B22/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
 Reading from private effective user settings.
 SignalR :: Connected (670139-com.apple.main-thread)
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: _s with parameters: {
 <FIRAnalytics/ERROR> Event name is reserved. Ignoring event: session_start
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: (null) with parameters: (null)
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: (null) with parameters: (null)
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event
 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: (null) with parameters: (null)
 <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Attempted to log nil event
```

**EDIT**

I removed the ".json" extension from the config file. Logs said :

```
GoogleTagManager warning: No default container found. Container needs to be added to a container folder and added to the target.
Configuration was not found in database. The configuration will be fetched from the network when necessary
Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events
Firebase Analytics enabled
Fetching configuration from the server
Downloading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:...
Successful fetched configuration from the server. Got network response. Code, size: 200, 106
Successfully parsed a configuration. Version: 1484056.........
Measurement data sent to network
Successful upload. Got network response. Code, size: 204, 0
```

any ideas ???

but errors are gone ???

Any ideas

**EDIT 2**

Upgraded Pods to latest :

> - Firebase/Core (3.14.0):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.7.0)
>   - FirebaseCore (= 3.5.1)
> - FirebaseAnalytics (3.7.0):
>
>   - FirebaseCore (~> 3.5)
>   - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseCore (3.5.1):
>
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)
> - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
> - GoogleAnalytics (3.17.0)
> - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
> - GoogleTagManager (5.0.8):
>
>   - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleAnalytics (~> 3.0)
>   - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3.0)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.1)
> - GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.1):
>
>   - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.1)
> - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
>
>   - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)

But still getting reserved event Errors :

```
2017-03-02 11:00:17.854 <Error> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS013006] Event name is reserved. Ignoring event: user_engagement
2017-03-02 11:00:17.854 GoogleTagManager info: Processing logged event: (null) with parameters: (null)
```

Funny thing is Firebase is ignoring event which :

- is reserved by Firebase or GTM
- i am not sending

:(

Comment: Check your code and see if you have FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: '', parameters: nil) or similar

Comment: logEvent accepts nil ??? but to be sure i check for nil and send a dictionary with 1 temp value. No change :(

Comment: I think it not accepts nil, just wanted to double check that. Just to be sure, your logs names are not starting with underscore, right?

Comment: open class func logEvent(withName name: String, parameters: [String : NSObject]?)

Comment: I mean the name of the events you are logging. I can see in the log you posted that you are trying to log an event called _s, but as Firebase documentation says: Must not start with an underscore and must consist of letters, digits and/or underscores

Comment: event names do not contain underscore they are all camelCase and i am not logging _s event it is auto logged

Comment: My comment is based on your edit. When you removed .json, TagManager weren't able to find your container and fetched a new one associated with your GTM ID. If you are not seeing the error anymore, the issue might be caused by your default container. Can you download your default container again? Please, double check through Firebase Analytics UI or verbose logging if your events are being logged.

Comment: I downloaded the container in both places (You can download 2 different file from 2 different places in Google Tag Manager and both have different contents) multiple times and the result was always same. So i am guessing Google Tag Manager and Firebase have internal integration problems. And also GTM is downloading a 3rd type of file online and it works

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was because of including files in a wrong way. Just be sure to include container folder properly. A tip : folder icon color shall be blue in project navigator.

Answer (score 0):

When you removed the json extension, Google Tag Manager wasn't able to find any container, and won't download a container. You can download the container from the publish screen, or from the versions page of your container.

The auto logged event "_s" is ignored, since Firebase Analytics will already have logged the event, and Google Tag Manager doesn't modify automatic events. You can use the "_s" event to trigger other tags, or trigger custom Firebase Analytics tags.

To trace the other warnings about the null event name, I'd search your code for any calls to logEvent that use an uninitialized variable.

Comment: I know the side effects of removing json extension. I did it on purpose to test the results. And it works better without it (no error logs which i complain). I am not using "_s" event and i have no idea what it is so that is absolutely Firebase or GTM internal problem. I seearched the code base there are no null event calls all events are calling a single function and it checks for string lenght. My guess is Firebase or GTM is giving this error after reserved event name stuff.